# Why does imagemagick convert increases file-size

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am using ImageMagick to convert png files to tiff. But after conversion the file size seems to increase by a huge amount? Any suggestion on what am i doing wrong here?
Command that I am using for conversion is : convert tiftest1.png tiftest2.png  output_file.tif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PNG files are analysed (filtered) on a line-by-line basis to see how best each line can be compressed relative to the previous one, then compressed. TIFF files, in general, are not.

You need to consider whether you can accept lossless or lossy compression and then tell the TIFF encoder.

If only lossless compression is acceptable:

```
magick input1.png input2.png -compress LZW result.tif
```

If lossy compression is acceptable (and compatible with downstream needs):

```
magick input1.png input2.png -compress JPEG result.tif
```

---

Check actual compression used in a file with:

```
magick identify -verbose image.tif
```

---

Check available types of compression with:

```
magick identify -list compress
```

Answer (score 0):

When converting to tiff, ImageMagick produces a non-compressed file by default. You can tell it to use LZW or ZIP or JPEG or other compressions. PNG is always compressed.